# Calculate the sum of series$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: calculus, fractions

I would like to calculate the sum of the following series by modifying the fraction.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

I came across an explanation that this fraction is equal to
$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)})$

It is easy then to calculate the sum which is equal to $\frac{1}{4}$, but I don't understand how to come up with that modification of a fraction. I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Hint: try it the other other way round, first compute $\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+y}$ for some reals $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It becomes telescoping sum $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(f(n)-f(n+1))=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}=\frac{1}{4}$$ where $$f(n)=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$.

Comment: @OnTheWay Almost like OP already did that...

Comment: @BrunoB Oh, sorry about that, i misunderstand OP question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the fraction like you posted:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)}} = \frac{a}{n} + \frac{b}{{n + 1}} + \frac{c}{{n + 2}}\\
 \Leftrightarrow a\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right) + bn\left( {n + 2} \right) + cn\left( {n + 1} \right) = 1\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
a + b + c = 0\\
3a + 2b + c = 0\\
2a = 1
\end{array} \right. \displaystyle\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
a = \frac{1}{2}\\
b =  - 1\\
c = \frac{1}{2}
\end{array} \right. \displaystyle\Rightarrow \frac{1}{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)}} = \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{1}{{n + 1}} + \frac{1}{{2\left( {n + 2} \right)}}\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{1}{{n + 1}} + \frac{1}{{2\left( {n + 2} \right)}} = \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{1}{{2\left( {n + 1} \right)}} - \left( {\frac{1}{{2\left( {n + 1} \right)}} - \frac{1}{{2\left( {n + 2} \right)}}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)}} - \frac{1}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)}}} \right)
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you very much - I suspect it is a partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: I mean, it works, but it's very convoluted... you could just notice that $(n+1)$ is in both of them and factor it out, and put it back in at the end.

Comment: @user4t48u Exactly, like i said, this is just a way to do this, always exists a better way, like Bruno B mentioned.

Comment: Still helps a lot, thank you both!

Comment: @user4t48u My pleasure, enjoy solving math bro.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to get the desired expression:

Take some reals $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq -x$, so that the fractions $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x+y}$ are defined.

Then:
$$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+y} = \frac{x + y - x}{x(x+y)} = \frac{y}{x(x+y)}$$

As such, if $y$ is also different from $0$:
$$\frac{1}{x(x+y)} = \frac{1}{y} \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+y}\right)$$

This gives you here:
$$\frac{1}{n(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)$$
and then you can just multiply by $\frac{1}{n+1}$.